# Cuntdown timer in cycle

Tags: java, android, countdowntimer

I'm trying to write code for a countdown timer with several conditions.

For processing I use several nested loops. But all timers works simultaneously. I need to start them sequentially. Advise, what to use.

```
try {
    for (int z = 1; z <= timerAll; z++) {
        for (int j = 1; j <= countEdu; j++) {
            showTimer(educ * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
            showTimer(rest * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
        }

        chStatus.setText("BIG REST");
        if(z== timerAll){
            chStatus.setText("DONE");
            //bigRest = 0;
            //timer.cancel();
        }
        showTimer(bigRest * MILLIS_PER_SECOND);
    }
} catch (NumberFormatException e) {
    // method ignores invalid (non-integer) input and waits
    // for something it can use
}
```

Comment: Did you take a look at this?
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/CountDownTimer.html

Comment: I have not problem with timer. Its work properly . I have problem with timer in  loop. I need to organize this timers to queue